# How to remove a dynamic string from a CSV file using sed?

Tags: sed

I added a dummy column at the beginning of my data export to a CSV file to get rid of control characters and some specific string values as mentioned below by using a pipe '|' delimiter. This data is coming from Teradata fast export using utf-8

```
'''
y^CDUMMYCOLUMN|
<86>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
<87>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
<94>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
{^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
_^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
y^CDUMMYCOLUMN|
[^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
k^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
m^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
<82>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
c^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
<8e>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
<85>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|
'''
```

This is completely random and not every row has these special characters. I'm sure I'm missing something here. I'm using sed to get rid of dummycolumn and control characters.

```
'''$ sed -e 's/.*DUMMYCOLUMN|//;/^$/d' data.csv > data_output.csv'''
```

After running this statement, I'm still remaining these below random values.

```
'''
<86>
<87>
<85>
<94>
<8a>
<85>
<8e>
'''
```

I could have written a sed statement to remove first three letters from each row but this series is not appearing in every row. At the same time, row count is 400 Million.

Current output.

```
y^CDUMMYCOLUMN|COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3
<86>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|6218915846|36596|12
<87>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|9822354765|35325|33
t^ADUMMYCOLUMN|6788793999|111|12
g^ADUMMYCOLUMN|6090724004|7017|12
_^ADUMMYCOLUMN|IC-21357688806502|111|12
<8e>^ADUMMYCOLUMN|9682027117|35335|33
v^ADUMMYCOLUMN|6406807681|121|12
h^ADUMMYCOLUMN|6346768510|121|12
V^ADUMMYCOLUMN|6130452510|7017|12
```

Desired Output

```
COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3
6218915846|36596|12
9822354765|35325|33
6788793999|111|12
6090724004|7017|12
IC-21357688806502|111|12
9682027117|35335|33
6406807681|121|12
6346768510|121|12
6130452510|7017|12
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: My apologies. Added the current input and desired output format.

Comment: Why not `sed 's/^[^|]*|//'` file? That will strip though the first `'|'` on each line?

Comment: Where does `12` and `33` in your desired output come from?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I tried your route, it won't take out the string. Instead it throws a new character.

▒DUMMYCOLUMN

Comment: @Cyrus, I made edits while posting the live data only in the desired output. I made the necessary changes in both places.

Comment: From my point of view you only want to remove the first column. This might help: `cut -d '|' -f 2- file.csv`

Comment: `it throws a new character. ▒DUMMYCOLUMN` You have to show the input file as it is, at best show `hexdump` of few `head` lines. [the input you presented works with](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DefinitiveWhitesmokeFiletype#main.sh).

Comment: @KamilCuk, I agree. In my case, it's only removing until dummycolumn in the header section. Whereas, in rows everything is still intact.

Comment: @Cyrus, I tried this against 100k rows and cut function did not work on all rows.

Comment: Which implementation and version of `sed` are you using? What OS? What `locale` does the script see? You show desired output, but what is current output (for the sample input you gave)?

Comment: @jhnc,NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.7 (Maipo)". Actually, the current input version is the current output.

Comment: It's better to edit the question with the extra details. What version of `sed` (eg. `sed --version`, `rpm -q --whatprovides $(which sed)`, etc)? What is output of `locale`? Show short sample of current input and current output as encoded binary (eg. run through `xxd` or `od -c`)

Comment: As mentioned above, if you have a locale set, sed may be ignoring "invalid" multibyte characters. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Locale-Considerations. Have you tried setting the locale to C? `LC_ALL=C sed '...'`